# Question about applying effects on containers

Tags: apache-flex

I need to apply an effect on containers that on mouse over the container it get resized or expands while pushing other containers surrounding it and causing them to get resized too. Something similar to [this](http://www.adidas.com/us/homepage.asp)

Can someone provide me with an example or a hint on how to implement something like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like totally custom component with manually resized containers (for each container there is a list of affected ones). If you want to be sure, try to decompile it :)

More thoughts: every containers grows vertically of horizontally; so it splits all other into two groups, one of them gets free space and starts growing too... Then it all goes back in same order. I think for each container there is list of connected containers, who can grow if that container is grown in same direction. In any case, I don't think it's automatic behavior.